# Android Studio 3.0 vector drawables and LINT tools:ignore="VectorPath"

Tags: android, lint, android-vectordrawable

After upgrading to 3.0 Android Studio has started to complain about long paths in vector drawables.

The warning says:

> Very long vector path (7958 characters), which is bad for performance.
>   Considering reducing precision, removing minor details or rasterizing
>   vector. less... (⌘F1)  Using long vector paths is bad for performance.
>   There are several ways to make the pathData shorter: * Using less
>   precision * Removing some minor details * Using the Android Studio
>   vector conversion tool * Rasterizing the image (converting to PNG)

The documentation https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/vector-drawable-resources.html shows us how to use vector drawables in our apps, and recommends it over png's etc.

I have both been using the Android Studio Vector Conversion Tool and this excellent service for converting SVG's to vector drawables:
http://inloop.github.io/svg2android/

Are there other services that does more to reduce vector drawable complexity?
Where can I find guidelines on how 'advanced' my vector drawables can be?

Comment: I literally just released a vector drawable optimization tool called [`avdo`](https://github.com/alexjlockwood/avdo) about an hour ago. You might find it useful!

Answer (score 31):

Try optimizing the vector drawable using [`avocado`](https://github.com/alexjlockwood/avdo)! It should help reduce the complexity of your paths.

Comment: It reduced the size by 10.5% but unfortunately some of the paths are still too long according to lint. Is there a way to split up the paths or something? Or should I use png? One of the paths is 1595 characters.

Comment: Its redusing size of the files,no change in paths.

Comment: Read this [article](https://jhavishal10.medium.com/optimize-svgs-remove-lint-warning-of-the-long-vector-path-fe0b34f80782) once

Answer (score 13):

My path was around 1800 and i used [svg-path-editor](https://yqnn.github.io/svg-path-editor/) to lower to around 1000. Still showed the warning but quite close to the max 800

I am sure there is a better way to use this tool but i just copied the `pathData` from android studio xml to the Path box, pressed Round and got the result back to the xml

If your path is more than 2000, consider converting to png (with mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi...)

[image]

Answer (score 8):

There's an extra step you can add before using `svg2android`, which is running it through [svgo](https://www.npmjs.com/package/svgo)

An example pipeline that I use looks like (note that instead of the web tool, I'm using [svg2vectordrawable](https://github.com/Ashung/svg2vectordrawable))

```
~$ svgo image.svg --config=config -o image.svg.optimized
~$ s2v "image.svg.optimized image.xml
```

My `config` file looks like (you can play around with it to match your needs):

```
"plugins": [
    {
        "convertPathData": {
            "leadingZero": false,
            "floatPrecision": 2
         }
    }
]
```

Comment: This is a great great tip! Thanks a lot!

Comment: `leadingZero` must be present, otherwise you get `InvalidVectorPath` lint.

Comment: `"leadingZero": false` deactivates the leading zeros optimizations, which makes your end result have them

Answer (score 7):

Try to use [this tool](https://jakearchibald.github.io/svgomg/) by decreasing `Precision`.

Comment: This tool did not work for me. It reduced the file size by 85%. However, it resulted in "Error inflating class ImageView". When I unchecked "Remove Hidden Elements", it prevented the inflation error, but the file was only reduced by 20% which was not enough to avoid the lint warning.

Comment: It worked for me, but. the quality of resulting image was not good enough

Answer (score 3):

This may not be an ideal solution, but Initially I had drawn the vector asset in a single shot **as a single object**, this resulted in longer `<path>` problem. I started from scratch again and this time I split my object into many parts i.e. **I drew each part of my single object individually** and **later I grouped them** together (I used [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/)). As a result, when .svg converts to .xml the single `<path>` tag gets split into multiple shorter `<path>` tags.